# Exporting tables from phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to export a table from a database, using the command. But it gives errors. I will be glad to help. Thank you.
An unexpected beginning of the expression. (near "mysql" at position 0)
An unexpected beginning of the expression. (near "u" at position 8)
An unexpected beginning of the expression. (near "root" at position 10)
An unexpected beginning of the expression. (near "p" at position 16)
Unknown operator. (near "default" at position 20)

```
mysql> -u root -p --default-character-set=utf8 abidin_db help | iconv -c -f utf8 -t windows-1251 > output_file.csv
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please add to the question (using the "Edit" link under it) what are the errors? It will be difficult to help you without.

Comment: If you are running the above in phpmyadmin, then you mixed a command like export up with phpmyadmin.